# Why can't I redirect the page as I wish

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It can properly redirect away from
[localhost/gwtech/trangchu](https://localhost/gwtech/trangchu)
to
[localhost/gwtech/search/example](http://localhost/gwtech/search/example)
But on this
[localhost/gwtech/san-pham/example](http://localhost/gwtech/san-pham/example) 
it go to
[localhost/gwtech/san-pham/search](http://localhost/gwtech/search/example)
but I want it like
[localhost/gwtech/search/example](http://localhost/gwtech/search/example)
and show HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
My code:

```html
   

 <form method="post" action="search" modelAttribute="search" name="search" onsubmit="return validateSearch()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  type="text" id="txtsearch" path="tensanpham" name="search-field" value="" placeholder="Nhập tên sẩn phẩm...."/>
        <button type="submit"><h1>Find</h1><span class="icon fa fa-search"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

> Controller

```
@Autowired
public HomeServiceImpl homeService;
@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productService;
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/trangchu"})
public ModelAndView home(HttpSession session) {
    session.removeAttribute("LoginInfo2");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("users/index");
    mv.addObject("slides", homeService.GetDataSlides());
    mv.addObject("loaisp", homeService.GetLoaiSPs());
    mv.addObject("nsx", homeService.GetNSXs());
    mv.addObject("allsp", homeService.GetSPAlls());
    mv.setViewName("users/index");
    
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public void search(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse resp, @ModelAttribute("search") String search) throws IOException {
    String searchfield = request.getParameter("search-field");
    resp.sendRedirect("/gwtech/search/"+searchfield);
    
}


@Autowired
private DeProductServiceImpl deproductService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/san-pham","/san-pham/{masp}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deproduct(HttpSession session,@PathVariable String masp) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("users/detail-product");
    mv.addObject("loaisp", homeService.GetLoaiSPs());
    mv.addObject("nsx", homeService.GetNSXs());
    mv.addObject("spbysp", deproductService.GetSPBySP(masp));
    mv.addObject("allsp", homeService.GetSPAlls());
    mv.setViewName("users/detail-product");
    return mv;
}
```

> When I used Search on trangchu it run very well but on san-pham it go to [localhost/gwtech/san-pham/search](http://localhost/gwtech/search/example) and show HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search","/san-pham/search")
public void search(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse resp, @ModelAttribute("search") String search) throws IOException {
    String searchfield = request.getParameter("search-field");
    resp.sendRedirect("/gwtech/search/"+searchfield);
}
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because you are calling the wrong URL in your form action.

```
<form method="post" action="search" modelAttribute="search" name="search" onsubmit="return validateSearch()">
```

the action="search" will add search in the current URL i.e localhost/gwtech/san-pham/search

So change your form action as below

```
<form method="post" action="search" modelAttribute="/search" name="search" onsubmit="return validateSearch()">
```

It will work now. Let me know if any doubt.